# Upward Traversal to AccountId in OpportunityLineItem Trigger.New

Tags: apex, trigger

Wondering why I can't access the AccountId through upward traversal in the below instance.  This is in a Before trigger on OpportunityLineItem.

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<id>();
for (OpportunityLineItem oli : Trigger.new) {
        accountIds.add(oli.opportunity.AccountId);
```

Have also tried *oli.opportunity.Account.Id* to no avail.  When I debug it I get null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have access to fields outside the scope of the trigger record when referencing trigger.new. In order to access oli.opportunity.accountid, you will need to capture the OpporunityId values from the OpportunityLineItem records and run a query against Opportunity to return the AccountIds you need.

Answer (score 1):

Like John said, you have to query the database for the field.

```
List<OpportunityLineItem> oli = new List<OpportunityLineItem>([SELECT Opportunity.AccountId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()]);
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
for(OpportunityLineItem o : oli){
    accountIds.add(o.Opportunity.AccountId);
}
```